# Worklight 6.2. Encrypt iOS pushsender password in application descriptor

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am trying to encrypt the push sender password in application-descriptor following [Storing properties in encrypted format](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_storing_properties_in_encrypted_format.html) section of the tutorial.

However, when building the wlapp for iOS, I see following error message in Worklight Studio.

```
FWLST1040E: iphone build failed: com.worklight.common.util.WorklightCertificateException: Certificate error: Unable to process certificate: apns-certificate-production.p12
```

It appears that Worklight Studio trying to decrypt the p12 certificate using '${xxxx}' as the password during build process. If I put the password as clear text, build passes. Replacing push sender values for GCM with ${xxx} passes also since there is no iOS-like certificate to decrypt. Only iOS build has problem here.

As far as I understand, the encrypted/configurable fields should be decrypted/replaced at server side during run time, not during the build. Right now, I am not able to build a new wlapp for ios because of this issue.

I am not sure what have I done wrong here. Is there a setting to skip the p12 decryption during build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight 6.2:

- Created a test=1234 in worklight.properties
- Using `<pushSender password="${test}" />` in application-descriptor.xml

This passes w/out any errors.

MobileFirst 6,3 7.0:
The same steps as above fail with:

> [2015-05-20 10:30:01] FWLST1040E: iphone build failed:
>   com.worklight.common.util.WorklightCertificateException: Certificate
>   error: Unable to process certificate: apns-certificate-sandbox.p12

I have opened a bug for it.

Are you sure about the version you're using?

Comment: That's weird... Because if I look at the Design editor for application-descriptor.xml, for the PushSender item, there is hint message saying "Defines the password to the SSL certificate encrypting the communication link with APNS. Note that the password attribute can refer to a property in worklight.properties file and can thus be encrypted. Example: ${myapp.ios.push.password}". 

And according to my test, putting variable values for all other fields works as expected.

Comment: That's interesting indeed. Sorry then! I retract my answer until this is tested. Meanwhile you can also open a pmr to receive official IBM support.

Comment: I have tried 6.2.0.0-20141216-0427 and 6.2.0.0-20140915-1601. Both have the same error.

Comment: Both are incredibly old builds. The latest 6.2 build is  6.2.0.1-20150520-0447. I used 6.2.0.01-20150407-0051. Make sure to use the latest fix from IBM Fix Central - note: I old used a value from worklight.properties - I did not actually encrypt it. Also try w/out encryption to make sure the error happens only when encrypting.

Comment: Confirmed using 6.2.0.01-20150430-1522 the build process passes without a problem... Thanks for the help.